# How to grant permission to other gmail accounts for google app script execution api?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I followed the tutorials in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js and used app engine to write the javascript functions to call some app script functions.

All the functions work well with the email I registered in google drive.

I am trying to add a new gmail user so that when they login to the app engine app they will be able to get the data from the same sheet.

Instead I am getting 401 or 403 errors

```
Error calling API: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
        "errorMessage": "Authorization is required to perform that action.",
        "errorType": "ScriptError"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried to add the users in the script api project on app engine developer console under IAM & Admin. But it still doesn't work.

So how do I add users email to grant them permission? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, by waiting a more detailed answers. For me what you need is for the second account to run script as the owner and this is for me not possible with execution api. My advice would be to create a web app you publish with the right to run with owner credentials and you call the url with an urlfetch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the solutions [here](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/posts/H8dLDP5Le6M) for your problem about your error code 401. Make sure you generated the correct credentials from the API project associated with your script. Also, you need to enable the "Google Apps Script Execution API". Check this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#general_procedure) on how to do that.

For your question on **"how to add users email to grant them permission?"**

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#granting_access_rights).